# What is the probability space for Poisson process?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm studying discrete stochastic processes using notes and lectures of prof. Gallager [1], and I was wondering if somebody could intuitively explain what the probability space (usually $\Omega$) for Poisson processes is. Or how to understand that?

Particularly, in the text they say that these events are equal:
$$\{S_n > t\} = \{N(t) < n\}$$

- $S_n$ is the time of n-th arrival
- $N(t)$ is number of arrivals at time $t$

Assuming that an event is a set, I should be able to see that the set that the LHS generates is the same as the set that RHS generates. But I can't see how I can find these sets.

Could somebody help me with that please?

[1] Page 71 here: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-262-discrete-stochastic-processes-spring-2011/course-notes/MIT6_262S11_chap02.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One does not need to know what the probability space is to understand **anything** about Poisson processes.

In the case at hand, for every $t\geqslant0$, $N(t)=\max\{n\geqslant0\mid S_n\leqslant t\}$ with the convention that $S_0=0$. Equivalently, $N(t)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\mathbf 1_{S_k\leqslant t}$. Hence the event $[N(t)\geqslant n]$ corresponds to at least $n$ indexes $k\geqslant1$ being such that $S_k\leqslant t$, that is, to the fact that $S_k\leqslant t$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, or, equivalently (since the sequence $(S_k)$ is almost surely nondecreasing), to the fact that $S_n\leqslant t$.

Thus, $[N(t)\geqslant n]=[S_n\leqslant t]$. Can you conclude?

Comment: Thanks @Did! After reading it carefully 10 times I think I got the idea. Does that mean that $[N(t)\geqslant n]=[S_n\leqslant t]=$[$S_k\leqslant$ for every $1\leqslant k \leqslant n$]?

Comment: So that basically means that one can just use the assumptions given by the definition of an arrival process to derive this result? However, I'm still curious what is the probability space like so that I can relate this to the basic example of flipping a coin where the probability space was {0,1} or Bernoulli process {0,1}*.

Comment: One needs an i.i.d. sequence of exponentials hence $(\mathbb R_+)^\mathbb N$ is an option. Anyway, one knows from a general result or from an explicit construction that $[0,1]$ is enough to construct any countable independent family, hence $[0,1]$ would do, too.