# Sample space of a Poisson distributed random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution

> Let be $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{N}$ a Poisson-distributed random variable that denotes the occurences of events during a time interval $[0,t]$, where $t>0$.

This is a classic setting in our stochastic lecture when talking about the Poisson distribution. However, I can't find anything about the sample space $\Omega$? Our professor circumvents/avoids this issue every time.

How do we define/construct an appropriate sample space $\Omega$ if we deal with Poisson-distributed random variables? Maybe at this stage of my studies this is a bit too advanced. Or is there any chance to construct a sample space the same way we did when dealing with other discrete random variables, like coin flips, balls in bins etc...?

(There is a related question [What is the probability space for Poisson process?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565453/579544) but it didn't fully answered my problem)

Comment: The underlying space $\Omega$ can be lots of things really, and for most purposes isn't very relevant. For example, you can take $\Omega=\mathbb N_0$, the $\sigma$-algebra $2^{\mathbb N_0}$ and the measure defined by $\mathbb P(\{n\})=\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$, then $X(n)=n$ has the Poisson distribution

Comment: @jlammy, I don't quite understand how $\Omega=\mathbb{N}_0$ would apply in the above example of the time interval? If we consider the set $\{X=2\}$ then we have to collect all $\omega\in\mathbb{N}_0$ which denote the time intervals that have $2$ occurrences.

Comment: OK but here $\Omega=\mathbb N_0$ is (say) counting the number of people arriving at a shop in time $[0,t]$. This is basically analagous to a coins/bins construction. If you want to be even more explicit, start with $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B,\mu)$ where $\mu$ is the measure for an exponential distribution, then with product measure you can define an infinite iid sequence of exponentials (and hence a Poisson process) on $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. So with this as your space you may also define a Poisson distribution